# Odoo 16 - Modify Examples in Project Module

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, registry, odoo-16

I'm trying to modify the examples in Project Module:

But I can't update the 'project' registry ..

[image]

I have created a new registry

```
odoo.define("restructure_inherit_views.extend_project_task_kanban_examples", function(require) {
    "use strict";
    var kanbanExamplesRegistry = require("web.kanban_examples_registry");
    var {
        _lt
    } = require("web.core");
    var {
        registry
    } = require("@web/core/registry");
    var {
        renderToMarkup
    } = "@web/core/utils/render";
    const {
        markup
    } = owl;
    const greenBullet = markup(`<span class="o_status d-inline-block o_status_green"></span>`);
    const redBullet = markup(`<span class="o_status d-inline-block o_status_red"></span>`);
    const star = markup(`<a style="color: gold;" class="fa fa-star"></a>`);
    const clock = markup(`<a class="fa fa-clock-o"></a>`);
    const exampleData = {
        ghostColumns: [_lt("New"), _lt("Assigned"), _lt("In Progress"), _lt("Done"), ],
        applyExamplesText: _lt("Use This For My Project"),
        allowedGroupBys: ["stage_id"],
        examples: [{
            name: _lt("New Custom Example"),
            columns: [_lt("Brainstorm"), _lt("Research"), _lt("Draft"), _lt("Final Document"), ],
            get description() {
                return renderToMarkup("project.example.researchproject");
            },
            bullets: [greenBullet, redBullet],
        }, ],
    };
    kanbanExamplesRegistry.add("custom_project", exampleData);
    registry.category("kanban_examples").add("custom_project", exampleData);
});
```

But now I don't know how to use this registry.
Any Help please